# How to avoid a word to break in the last line of a paragraph

Tags: line-breaking

is any penalty value available to avoid a word break in a last line of a paragraph like below?

[image]

Comment: you could enter it as `\mbox{investment}` to prevent hyphenation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Both comments a bove provide the correct answer depending on whether you want only to "avoid/discourage" (use `\finalhyphendemerits`) or prevent (`\mbox`). However do *not* use `\mbox` to keep several words together, because then the spaces inside will not stretch or shrink but the other spaces in the line may. So if you really want to keep the last 2 or 3 words together you need something ugly like

```
   \mbox{last}~\mbox{three}~\mbox{words}.
```

(ignoring here that the words in my example are too short for hyphenation).

`\finalhyphendemerits` only makes that break less likely but will never prevent it if nothing else is feasible.

ps. if your text is real, then note that there is a space missing after one sentence ending.